# exception report

Tags: list, printing

I have a infopath form which add records to a list. This is regarding policy acceptance by users. Is there a way to generate report to identify who all did not complete the "Policy Acceptance" form? (one way is to maintain 2 lists and compare them, but how do you compare 2 list).

2nd question: Is there a way to print all the items in a list for the user who "Rejected" the policy? (BUT 1 RECORD PER PAGE)

Comment: could you give more details regarding your application? List columns, storage, workflow, etc.

Comment: They are just custom list.

Comment: Any thoughts on this guys. Need a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be at least two lists - UserList and PolicyAcceptance. The UserList contains user information and the PolicyAcceptance captures the input responses. One approach (without programming) would be to link the two lists and creating views (reports) based on the responses. Here are posts that can be of help -

[Create Linked Lists in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff728095.aspx).

[How to Link Two List and Create a combine view in the SharePoint 2010](http://melick-rajee.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-link-two-list-and-create-combine.html)

Answer (score -3):

Check out www.samepagesoftware.com.  They have a SharePoint 2010 solution that does exactly this.  It can be used for any list or document library and can look for any number of entries within a user specified date range.

Comment: Please note that, [per the FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) you must disclose your affiliation in your answers (accept you didn't attempt to conceal this, but wording could be more explicit). If your objective is to quietly drum up a bit of traffic for your blog or product, this is probably the wrong place for you. [mod]